# ASP Do While loop totals and subtotals

Tags: loops, asp-classic, do-while

I don't claim to be a classic ASP guy, but sometimes you gotta do what you gotta do.  My problem is that this is a custom built report through ASP and the user wants running SubTotals and a Grand Total displayed as well, and honestly I'm just not sure how to go about it.  Currently the entire report is wrapped like this, the way it's displayed doesn't matter too much to the issue.

```
<%do while (adoRsTrade.AbsolutePage = iPageCurrent) and (not adoRsTrade.EOF)
NewRep = adoRsTrade("calIncludedRep")

if CurRep <> NewRep or FirstTime="T" and (not adorsTrade.BOF) then %>
```

add up the values for that CurRep and display them as 'subtotals'

```
<%

FirstTime="F"
CurRep = adoRsTrade("calIncludedRep")
adoRsTrade.MoveNext
loop %>
```

any help i could get would be greatly appreciated as i mentioned I am not an ASP guru by any means.
Thank you,
NickG

to update the subtotal stuff; the grand totals are completed since i can just re-run a do while loop outside of the loop the displays all of the data and total it, easy-peezy (not really) now what i run into is that the .MoveNext is hit prior to me being able to check the NewRep; here is the totalling of sub-totals as well as the check if it's a newrep which means display the sub-totals for the former rep

```
<%do while (adoRsTrade.AbsolutePage = iPageCurrent) and (not adoRsTrade.EOF)
NewRep = adoRsTrade("calIncludedRep")

if CurRep = NewRep then
        curPrincipal = adoRsTrade("mPrincipal")
        totPrincipal = totPrincipal + curPrincipal
            curInterest = adoRsTrade("mInterest")
            totInterest = totInterest + curInterest
        curCommission = adoRsTrade("calCommission")
        totCommission = totCommission + curCommission
            curSECFee = adoRsTrade("mSECFee")
            totSECFee = totSECFee + curSECFee
        curSvcFee = adoRsTrade("mSvcCharge")
        totSvcFee = totSvcFee + curSvcFee
            curNet = adoRsTrade("mNetAmount")
            totNet = totNet + curNet
end if    
if CurRep <> NewRep or FirstTime="T" and (not adorsTrade.BOF) then
  If FirstTime <> "T" then%>
      <TR>
        <td>
            <table class='FontStandardMinus1' border=0 cellPadding=0 align='left' cellSpacing=0 width="100%" bgcolor='#ffffff'>
                 <TR>
                    <td width="59%" align="left"><b>SubTotals<!-- for <%Response.Write(CurRep) %>-->:</b></td>
                    <td width="10%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totPrincipal,2)%></td>
                    <td width="7%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totInterest,2)%></td>
                    <td width="7%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totCommission,2)%></td>
                    <td width="5%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totSECFee,2)%></td>
                    <td width="4%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totSvcFee,2)%></td>
                    <td width="9%" valign=top align=right><%=FormatNumber(totNet,2)%></td>
                </TR>
            </table>
        </td>
    </TR>
<%end if      
curPrincipal = 0
totPrincipal = 0
curInterest = 0
totInterest = 0
curCommission = 0
totCommission = 0
curSECFee = 0
totSECFee = 0
curSvcFee = 0
totSvcFee = 0
curNet = 0
totNet = 0 %>
<TR>
<TD width="100%">
<table class='FontStandardMinus1' border=0 cellPadding=0 align='left' cellSpacing=0 width="100%" bgcolor='#ffffff'>
<tr>
<td width=100%><b><%=adoRsTrade("calIncludedRep")%></b></td>

</tr>
</table>
</TD>
</TR>
<%end if%>
<%

FirstTime="F"
'CalCom = CalCom + adoRsTrade("calCommission")
CurRep = adoRsTrade("calIncludedRep")
adoRsTrade.MoveNext

loop%>
```

so you can see i try to reset the values to 0 after displaying them in a table, but that table is only displayed after the .MoveNext is hit in the hit, which means even though i want to display records 1-5 added up, record 6 was already hit by the .MoveNext and is being discarded from the value set.  Sorry for the lengthiness of this but I hate that comments can't contain updated code.
thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you output the variables totPrincipal, totInterest , totCommission after the loop the only problem i can think of is the datatype and the rs.MoveFirst.

BTW: Try do do it in a single loop for performance reasons!

```
Dim subtotPrincipal: subtotPrincipal = 0
Dim totPrincipal: totPrincipal = 0
Dim CurRep: CurRep = 0
Dim NewRep: NewRep = 0

adoRsTrade.MoveFirst
Do 
    NewRep = adoRsTrade("calIncludedRep")       
    ...
    subtotPrincipal = subtotPrincipal + CLng(adoRsTrade("mPrincipal"))
    totPrincipal = totPrincipal + CLng(adoRsTrade("mPrincipal"))
    ...

    If (CurRep <> NewRep And Not adorsTrade.BOF) Or adoRsTrade.EOF Then
        Response.Write subtotPrincipal
        subtotPrincipal = 0
    End If

    CurRep = NewRep
    adorsTrade.MoveNext
Loop Until adoRsTrade.EOF

Response.Write totPrincipal
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i was able to get the grand totals working correctly by using the MoveFirst outside of the loop above after checking to make sure that i was on the last page. so that's a big step.  However, the subtotals are giving me problems because they keep adding what is supposed to be the 1st value of the next set after i display.  I even reset all the variables to = 0 after displaying but the next value is added into those, not sure where to go but thank you for your help so far!

Comment: I don't think that I can do it without a nested loop, the grandtotals work fine since they are outside of the loop to display data but sub-totals are killing me, i updated my post with more info if you could take a look, i understand fi you're busy and appreciate the help more than i could tell ya

Comment: Ok just a few comments: 1. you must order your data by calIncludedRep in the SQL because otherwise this solution will never work 2. you coud simplify the adding by eg. `totPrincipal = totPrincipal + adoRsTrade("mPrincipal")`and remove the resetting to zero 3. You are setting the flag `FirstTime` after the first iteration to F no mather what - I can't see the sense in that? 4. Check the nested IFs - I don't think these are necessary - why don' you just write out the subtotals and the separation in one step?

Comment: I actually figured it out, I was resetting the values after already adding the first value of the new record set which was causing my data to be off a little bit.  now the only thing I have to figure out is how to get the subtotal for the last record in the dataset which i am unsure of.  using If AdorsTrade.Index = (AdorsTrade.RecordCount - 1) doesn't do it, but thank you for everything you've definitely been the only reason i got where i am

Comment: glad you figured it out! - you could store the `RecordCount`in a variable `rsCount=AdorsTrade.RecordCount` (don't forget to use `adodb.CursorLocation = 3`) and then compare it with a simple incrementing variable `count = count + 1` at the end of the loop.